# Laravel 5.2: Cascading dropdown doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a cascading dropdownlist when If i select a category subcategories also will be changed . I used Ajax here.I don't know why my subcategories couldn't load in the view while i select category list from dropdown.

Here is my routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {

     $categories=\App\Category::all();
    return view('index')->with ('categories',$categories);

});

Route::get('/ajax-subcat',function(){
    $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
    $subcategories=Subcategory::where('category_id','=',$cat_id)->get();
    return Response::json($subcategories);
});
```

And here is my View page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cascading Dropwon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Categories and Subcategories Ajax</h3>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '','files'=>true))  !!}
                {!! Form::token(); !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Categories</label>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="category" id="category">
                        @foreach($categories as $category){
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                        }
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Sub Categories</label>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                {!!Form::close()!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#category').on('change',function(e){
                console.log(e);
                var cat_id = e.target.value;

                $.get('/ajax-subcat?cat_id='+ cat_id,function(data){
                    $('#subcategory').empty();
                    $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){
                        $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+
                                                    subcatObj.name+'</option>');
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is my model of Subcategories:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model{
     protected $table="subcategories";
     protected $fillable = ['name','category_id'];
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you show the log you get after calling your ajax route go get subcategories? Do you get any errors in the network tab in developer tools?

Comment: Yes it's showing Object No found means it's not getting the id of #Category

Comment: Is that your complete route.php or snippet of it? I'm trying to see if the ajax route is under any middleware that check for csrf since the ajax request doesn't include the token.

Comment: Inside the change event function, what do you get if you log cat_id var? Does it contain the correct value? you can also grab the cat_id like this: $(this).val()